# mysql update (i want to change the string last two character)

Tags: mysql

i have a string

```
www.baabrada.aapnipanchayat.org
```

i want to change the string

```
www.baabrada.aapnipanchayat.in
```

and i have use this update query

```
UPDATE `gram_panchayat` SET web=in WHERE web=org;
```

Answer (score 7):

Ensures what `.org` be replaced with `.in` only at the end of string:

```
UPDATE gram_panchayat
  SET web = CONCAT(LEFT(web, CHAR_LENGTH(web)-CHAR_LENGTH('org')), 'in')
  WHERE web LIKE '%.org'
```

Test it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e78a26/1

More info: [String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I disagree this time. This is absolutely the better and safer answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to use [the `INSERT()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_insert):

```
UPDATE gram_panchayat
SET web = INSERT(web,
                 CHAR_LENGTH(web) - CHAR_LENGTH('org') + 1,
                 CHAR_LENGTH('org'),
                 'in'
                )
WHERE web LIKE '%.org';
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle demo to play with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/524905/1